# Can a COM interface return a integer instead of a long?

Tags: mfc, com

Here is my class and associated interface:

```
[Guid("xx")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IStudentItem
{
    string Type { get; set; }
    DateTime Week { get; set; }
    int Study { get; set; }
}

[Guid("yy")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class StudentItem : IStudentItem
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Week { get; set; }
    public int Study { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, `Study` is defined as a `int`.

But in the MFC side, when I am using this property, I end up with a `long`:

```
long lStudyNumber = 0;
if(SUCCEEDED(studentItem->get_Study(&lStudyNumber)))
    oEntry.iStudyPoint = static_cast<int>(lStudyNumber);
```

My DLL is in both 86x and 64x editions. Is there any way to get the `get_Study` property to return a `integer` instead?

Comment: You are focusing on a non-existing problem.  An `int` in a C# program is a 32-bit value.  It always appears as `long` in COM type libraries, also a 32-bit value for MSVC++.  This convention goes back to the days that `int` was *not* a 32-bit value yet, COM was first implemented on the 16-bit version of Windows.  And thus required `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want this. Use an appropriate type that makes sense for the data in all OS and bitness.

You can use int. COMs know the __int3264 type in the MIDL compiler and inside the TLB (type libraries) and even a VARIANT has the VT_INT type.

So also an IDispatch driven automation will receive the correspondent value.

But be aware that even than there is some marshaling, when you have 64bit external COM Server and a 32bit process asks for data, the marshaller will transform the previous VT_INT into a VT_I8... On the other hand a 32bit external COM server will return an VT_INT as a VT_I4 to a 64bit process...

Comment: I don't particularly want anything. My 32 process calls the 32 bit DLL and the 64 bit process calls the 64 bit DLL. I am happy to leave it as it is. The actual values will always be under 100. The existing code was using `integer` so I was just looking for simplification. I hear what you are saying though. I guess, with the COM using `long` it is going to be the same for compile bit compilations.

Comment: Yes. Or use short int.. or what ever.